Get More Rows in a Single Page in Pagination in BigQuery API
While using BigQuery API, I understand the limit of 10 MB of data/rows per page, how do I increase it, so that I can get more data/rows in a single page while paginating through the whole data. I tried to go through documentation, and found that I can go to support and raise a request to increase the limit to 20 MB, can someone help with that.

Have a read at the following article which describes how to request a quota change.  Follow the steps.
https://cloud.google.com/docs/quotas/view-manage#requesting_higher_quota
